# Azure SQL Reporting Returns "Item Not Found"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-reporting

I am trying to render a report using the ReportExecution2005 web service. I have no problems rendering a report locally, but when I try to call it on Azure, it always fails with the message that the item can't be found.

The report is called "Invoice.rdl". Here's how I'm calling it (snippet):

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService()
{
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
    ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader,
    Url = string.Format("https://{0}:443/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.amsx", "myUrl")
}

rs.LogonUser("myUsername", "myPassword", "myUrl");

rs.LoadReport("/Reports/Invoice", _historyId); // here the exception is thrown
```

I've tried it with different paths, e.g. `/Invoice`, `/SSRSReport/Invoice`, `/ReportServer/Invoice` etc., none seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: [SQL Reporting will discontinue service on October 31, 2014.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-reporting/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turned out to be a stupid problem.
When uploading the report from the old Windows Azure management portal, it would leave the ".rdl" file extension in the name.

Removing it fixed the problem.